# Testing functions through I/O in Haskell

Tags: debugging, haskell, testing

I'm playing codewars to sharpen my Haskell skills, and running into a problem that I haven't had in imperative languages.

Let's say I'm writing a function foo() in javascript, which takes an int, adds two, squares it, subtracts one, and returns the square root of that number.

```
var foo = function(n) {
  n += 2;
  n = n * n;
  n -= 1;
  n = Math.sqrt(n);
}
```

I want to check on the state of the data being processed in the function at various points to help me troubleshoot/revise/debug code, so I will insert console.log() statements whenever I want to see where I'm at.  For example, am I, in fact, squaring the sum of n+2 correctly halfway through the function?  Let's see...

```
var foo = function(n) {
  n += 2;
  n = n * n;
  console.log("n = " + n);
  n -= 1;
  n = Math.sqrt(n);
}
```

While this example should be simple enough for a Haskeller to write in one line, if you have a complex function and want to check the state at different points, how do Haskellers do it?  Is there a standard practice using the IO() monad?  Do they get around it some other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GHCi has a fancy [debugger](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html) that lets you step through your code and evaluate it line by line, checking it's state and intermediary results.

But, of course, there is also the `printf`-style debugging that you are asking for, using the `trace` function from `Debug.Trace`. Nothing wrong with using that for small scripts imho, but it's generally discouraged.

`trace` has the type `String -> a -> a`, so you pass a string that gets printed (via `unsafePerformIO`) and any argument that gets simply returned.

---

In your example we could use it as follows. This is your function translated to Haskell:

```
foo x = sqrt $ (x+2)**2 - 1
```

Now we can just add `trace` and the string we want to see, e.g. `"Debug Me: " ++ (show ((x+2)**2))`. First import `Debug.Trace`, though:

```
import Debug.Trace
foo x = sqrt $ (trace ("Debug Me: " ++ (show ((x+2)**2))) ((x+2)**2)) - 1
```

A bit ugly? Following David Young's comment below, we better use `traceShowId :: Show a => a -> a`, if what we want to output is identical to the intermediary result (converted to `String`, of course):

```
import Debug.Trace
foo x = sqrt $ (traceShowId ((x+2)**2)) - 1
```

---

See [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Debugging) for a summary of debugging options.

Comment: `trace (show y) y` can be simplified as `traceShowId y`

Comment: Yes! Fixed it above.